# A model to explain Partial Reflection?

Tags: visible-light, photons

As smart as Newton was, in the end he realized he had not yet developed a satisfactory theory for partial reflection. 300 years later Richard Feynman says "we haven't got a good model to explain partial reflection by two surfaces; we just calculate the probabilities that a particular photo multiplier will be hit."
Question: are there still no models to explain partial reflection?

Comment: There is a perfectly good theory in classical electromagnetism; Feynman's comment is essentially equivalent to saying that we don't have a detailed, general, and microscopic understanding of how decoherence leads to Born-rule selection in the quantal picture. *::shrugs::* As far as I know that continues to be the case.

Comment: I acknowledged that Feynman said we could calculate probabilities (Born rule). If I have to rephrase my question to say microscopic understanding  then so be it. Is there a physical model that describes how partial reflection goes from 0 to 16%? Does classical electromagnetism explain this and where? Thanks

Comment: Yes, classical electromagnetism explains it in terms of continuity across a boundary with varying permiability and permitivity. I think the basic situation can be explained in a page or two, but to justify the statements used in the short version requires a significant fraction of a typical upper division E&M text

Comment: Am I missing something, or isn't this just the Fresnel equations, the derivation of which are in any undergrad physics book?

Comment: Somewhere someone must have written a nice short version that physically explains what's going on. I would be happy with A upper division E&M text if there was a section that physically explained partial reflection.  Feynman one by one went through a list of proposed ideas and one by one check them off. At least he was looking for a physical model to explain the partial reflection.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks but I have already acknowledged twice that these probabilities can be calculated. I am only asking what Feynman himself ask what is really going on physically that determines these percentages?. Feynman himself said we haven't got a good model. He was thinking, wondering and interested in what that model would be as I am.

Comment: @JohnRennie this is something I am truly interested in. I am specifically interested in how the thickness of the glass affects the percentage of reflection from 0 to 16%. I am interested in this in the same way Feynman was. He knew we could calculate this but said "we have not been able to find any system of logic that consummate with ordinary ideas like causality that will explain or describe this" he really wanted to find a physical model to explain this and didn't like having to rely on probability calculation.

Comment: He went on to say "we have a set of rules that are empty of a model" it's that model that I am interested in and asking about. Everyone keeps saying you can find it in the textbooks but I believe they are only talking about the probability calculations and not an actual model. So my original question is: Has anyone come up with a model yet? If the answer is yes please let me know where this is. Thanks